# Using Java to Export Binary Data from SQL Server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, blob

I have a database table with 7500 records in it.  I am trying to write something that can export all 7500 jpg images to a folder on my laptop and name them based on EMPID + TYPE.

[image]

So the blob would be named 1008421_0.jpg for the first row

I was thinking something like this but how do i name each image?

```
String filePath = "C:/Photos/";
 try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM MMOBJ WHERE EMPID > 1 ";
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        while (result.next()) {
            Blob blob = result.getBlob("photo");
            InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question... Please be more specific the next time.

As a matter of fact, you do need a loop iteration for each row. I would suggest exchanging the `if (result.next())` with `while (result.next())`. 
Furthermore, your `filePath` seems to be constant, but should depend on `EMPID` if my understanding of your question is correct.

Finally, don't forget to close `Statement` and/or `ResultSet` to avoid resource leaks.

Comment: Hi Samjaf, Thanks for your response, my filepath is  String filePath = "C:/Photos/Test.jpg"; So that would mean that every image is named test.jpg?  I will look into changing that.  Thanks again for your response.

Comment: I have edited my question to incorporate your suggestions and add clarity to what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to change the filename for each row using this.

```
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        while (result.next()) {
            Blob blob = result.getBlob("LNL_BLOB");
            String name = result.getString("EMPID");
            InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath+name+".jpg");
```

Thanks for your assistance.